# If value doesn't exist OR has true value

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

In my final `deployment.yaml` created from helm template I would like to have liveness and readiness blocks only if in `values.yaml` the block `.Values.livenessReadinessProbe` **doesn't exist** or if `.Values.livenessReadinessProbe.enabled` **is true**.

I tried to do it so:

```
  {{- if or (not .Values.livenessReadinessProbe) (.Values.livenessReadinessProbe.enabled) }}
  livenessProbe:
    httpGet:
      path: /actuator/health/liveness
      port: 8080
    initialDelaySeconds: 300
    failureThreshold: 5
    periodSeconds: 10
  readinessProbe:
    httpGet:
      path: /actuator/health/readiness
      port: 8080
    initialDelaySeconds: 200
    failureThreshold: 5
    periodSeconds: 10
  {{- end }}
```

But I'm getting `nil pointer evaluating interface {}.enabled`, if `livenessReadinessProbe` is absent in `values.yaml`, so it seems like the second OR condition is being executed, even though the first condition is `true` (i.e. `.Values.livenessReadinessProbe` is absent).

How can I achieve it?

My `values.yaml` with existing `livenessReadinessProbe` value:

```
livenessReadinessProbe:
  enabled: true
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Go `text/template` language](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template), `and` and `or` are *functions*, not built-in operators, so they don't have the usual "short-circuiting" semantics: first they evaluate all of their arguments, and then `or` returns the first that is true.

What I'd do here is use `default` to provide an empty dictionary as a default value.  That is still "false" so you can use it in conditionals, but now since it's a dictionary, you can do an index lookup in it.

```yaml
{{- $lrp := .Values.livenessReadinessProbe | default dict }}
{{- if or (not $lrp) $lrp.enabled }}
livenessProbe: { ... }
readinessProbe: { ... }
{{- end }}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to have liveness and readiness blocks only if in
> values.yaml the block .Values.livenessReadinessProbe doesn't exist or
> if .Values.livenessReadinessProbe.enabled is true.

You can test it [here](https://helm-playground.com/):

template.yaml

```
{{- if .Values.livenessReadinessProbe }}
{{- if eq (.Values.livenessReadinessProbe.enabled) true }}
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /actuator/health/liveness
    port: 8080
  initialDelaySeconds: 300
  failureThreshold: 5
  periodSeconds: 10
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /actuator/health/readiness
    port: 8080
  initialDelaySeconds: 200
  failureThreshold: 5
  periodSeconds: 10
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

values.yaml

```
livenessReadinessProbe:
  enabled: true
```

See the output when you adjust the values.yaml:

- Delete `livenessReadinessProbe.enabled`, or set it to false.
- Delete the entire value block.

Comment: Actually I needed that without `livenessReadinessProbe` in `values.yaml` this block should also be rendered, but bold +1 from me for the helm-playground!

Comment: A simple `else` can do that easily. But a better way is set the default `livenessReadinessProbe: {}` in your values.yaml, so that using `enabled` key under `livenessReadinessProbe` become meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the function:

(From: [If condition checking value returned by helm template](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61145630/))

> ```
> {{- define "isFlagEnabled" -}}
> {{- if .Values.global -}} {{/* <-- check parent exists to avoid nil pointer evaluating interface {}.myflag */}}
> {{- if .Values.global.myflag -}}
> {{- .Values.global.myflag -}}
> {{- end -}}
> {{- else if .Values.myflag -}} {{/* <-- make sure its else if so you wont override if both defined */}}
> {{- .Values.myflag -}}
> {{- else -}}
> {{- printf "false" }}
> {{- end -}}
> {{- end -}}
> ```

use in **template**

```
 {{- define "flagUsage" -}}
    {{- if eq (include "isFlagEnabled" .) "true" -}}
    {{- printf "%s" (include "isFlagEnabled" .) -}}
    livenessProbe:
    httpGet:
      path: /actuator/health/liveness
      port: 8080
    initialDelaySeconds: 300
    failureThreshold: 5
    periodSeconds: 10
  readinessProbe:
    httpGet:
      path: /actuator/health/readiness
      port: 8080
    initialDelaySeconds: 200
    failureThreshold: 5
    periodSeconds: 10
    {{- end -}}
    {{- end -}}
```

Comment: Do you think there is no easier solution?

Comment: there could be for sure a ternary function or so, however, personally i found it simple and could be extended as per requirement so.